# Vegan biscuits/snacks for dogs

Tags: veganism, food, pets

I used to feed stray puppies [Britannia's Marie Biscuits](http://britannia.co.in/products/marie-gold/marie-gold). After looking at the ingredients I saw that it contains milk and is not vegan.

Does anyone know what other vegan biscuits/snacks I can feed them? I only feed them just 2 biscuits each and they eat from garbage.

My family is a normal stereotypical Indian family and hence I cannot do much for them, for now.

I have tried to find biscuits without milk, but I could not find any. Is there any other snack or something?

Comment: Dogs need not to be vegan. We should not force our choices on our animals. Dogs are carnivorous animals. Aren't they? It doesn't matter if they eat the food they eat i.e., meat. I would not force my intentions on my pets.

Comment: @NogShine Animals want to live, dont they? It does not matter what food my animal friends eat i.e., vegan. i would not forcibly kill an organism to feed the other. We should not forcibly kill animals. Thank you for your opinion. I would love to see your reaction when hens, cows, turkeys start eating dogs.

Comment: @NogShine This is a valid question -- the OP is looking for a way to feed them without increasing the consumption of milk (they wouldn't be drinking directly from cows on their own). Further discussion should go to [chat], please.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you find any without milk to be honest. But on the subject, you can perhaps try to make your own, dogs aren't that picky. However, do not give them chocolate and don't make any dogs full vegan as it will damage their health.

Comment: Please also see [this meta question](https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/240/70) regarding the broader issue of a vegan diet for carnivorous animals. I'd appreciate the community input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various companies that make vegan dog treats. Here's a few, though I'm not sure how many ship worldwide.

- Antler dog chews make [sweet potato treats](https://www.antlerdogchews.co.uk/sweet-potato-treats) which they say consist of 100% sweet potato.
- Berriewood pet supplies do [Carrot slices dog treats](https://www.berriewoodwholesale.co.uk/Burns-Dried-Carrot-Slices-Dog-Treats/c14062)
- Veggiepets [do a range of vegetarian and vegan treats](https://www.veggiepets.com/dogs/vegetarian-vegan-dog-biscuits)
- Head up for tails also [do a range of treats](https://www.headsupfortails.com/dog-food/dog-vegetarian-treats.html)

These companies generally warn you that if you're keeping a dog as a pet, they can't live on treats alone.

If you're happy to make rather than buy...

- PETA suggest [you can make your own treats](https://www.peta.org/living/animal-companions/homemade-carrot-date-oatmeal-vegan-dog-treats/) from carrot, date and oatmeal.
- Livekindly [also have some recipes](https://www.livekindly.co/vegan-dog-treats/)

Answer (score 0):

Not only treats and snacks, there exists a **complete dog food** (i.e. it can be the primary part of your dog's diet) which is fully vegan: [Benevo](https://www.vetshop.co.uk/Benevo-Vegan-Adult-Dry-Dog-Food-15kg?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8JCAlfWL8gIVBevtCh3m9Q2wEAQYAiABEgLJ1PD_BwE). This is a UK brand; I don't know if they ship internationally.

> Benevo Vegan Adult Dry Dog Food is a nutritionally complete and balanced vegan adult dog food with added Taurine and L-Carnitine, the first of its kind. Made in the UK, Benevo Adult Original dong *[sic]* food features a wheat-free formulation with a powerful 27% protein, added protein to aid digestion and added Yucca extract to reduce odours. There are no artificial flavours or colours.

> Our products are approved by the UK Vegan Society and Vegetarian Society.

> **Ingredients:** Soya, Corn, White Rice, Sunflower Oil, Peas, Brewers Yeast, Beet Pulp, Tomato Pomace, Yeast Based Palatant, Minerals, Vitamins, Yucca Schidigera Extract (0.1%), Fructo-Oligosaccharides (Prebiotic FOS) (0.01%).

[image]